Github [Codespaces] rejecting pushes to Origin from Collaborators
The Short of It
I have a github repo meant to be used as a codespace. Collaborators have made github accounts, been added as "collaborators" on the repo, then have gone to the repo page, created a codespace, and used git to checkout a branch, say example_branch.
After making a few commits to that branch and pushing it to origin/example_branch by Staging, Committing, and Syncing all using the VSCode / Codespaces browser GUI, they suddenly get an error upon clicking Sync telling them that they don't have permission to push and suggesting they fork the repository. I don't know why this error is occurring.
create codespace on main
The Plan
I'm a middle school teacher teaching a python course. I'd like to use github as an easy way for students to submit their assignments, rather than a low-tech way like copy+paste into google docs. I'll start by acknowledging that this isn't the intended use-case for git, but I truly thought my idea was straightforward enough to easily work.
The system I envisioned was having a branch off of main for each student. Each student made a git account, I added them as collaborators to my class repository, and they each checked out their own branch to commit their changes onto. They would never have merge or pull request these branches onto main, all they would need to do to submit their individual projects is push their commits up to the origin.
This would allow me to grade student projects quite easily. On my machine, I could git checkout student1-branch, see and run their code in my editor, then move on to the next student. It would also allow students to easily submit their work. For a middle school class, student work often looks like 100 students each making their own version of basic_turtle_loop_project.py. I don't want them merging these, just making their work available to me.
sketch of my desired system
The Problem
Git constantly rejects the students' push to origin calls. It gives them warnings they don't have permission, and suggests they fork the repo. I truly don't believe that forking will solve my problem - if I understand correctly, forking the repo will prevent me from easily accessing their code, which was the whole point of the system.
This is even something that happens after I have verified the system works as intended. Last week, I went through every student's system and ensured they could successfully push to their corresponding origin/student[n]-branch. I looked at "Active Branches" on my repo's github page and verified that each branch was active with 1 or more commits from the corresponding student. I had to reset some systems setups as they were already accidentally on forks. The next day, my changes seemed to be undone. Even though it had succeeded before, students were again getting the same error of "no permission, would you like to fork instead"?
Chromebooks & Codespaces
This is all happening on chromebooks, which could 100% be the cause. I've got a PC, but students only have chromebooks for class. In addition, my github repo is meant to be used as a github codespace. This allows me to get around some of the restrictions of a chromebook (no terminal access, at least on my schools' machines) and allow students to run python code from a terminal, in addition to letting them edit in VSCode (instead of a weaker editor like replit).
After creating the codespace on the first day of class, students checked out their personal branch. Then, students would just have to press Commit and Sync after finishing a project, like in the image below. It's possible I'm not understanding exactly what the Sync button is doing, but I've also tried git push --force in the terminal and gotten the same errors.
vscode github GUI
Students also don't have personal chromebooks. They are kept in carts in each classroom, and when they arrive in class pick one at random to sign into. They click on the bookmark for the codespace, at which point they are prompted to log into their github account.
Please Help 
This system was supposed to disappear into the background. I'm not trying to teach git in this class. The intended student experience from git is "unusual looking save button", and the intended teacher experience is "swap between each student's project with a single simple shell command, all inside VSCode for ease of running the project once swapped to".
This has been such a mess. I'm not sure why git is consistently rejecting their Sync commands. I'm going to have them copy+paste into google docs for the short term, which I know is absurd in 2024, but I've already wasted enough class time trying to fix this.

Do you really need the github UI?  You can set up your OWN git repository on a server you control.

Github codespaces as a tool for this class came first. Then, I already had the github UI as I needed it to set up the codespaces and repo. However, shouldn't I be able to do this basic task through github.com? What would being on my own server realistically gain me

Instead of trying to commit in the online VSCode terminal, why not have them make their own commits directly in their branch on the GitHub repository?
It could be a network permission or a limitation related to resource usage, since the online VSCode in GitHub has certain constraints because its tied to GitHub's infrastructure.

I'm not sure what you mean. It'd be nice for them to do everything from the same page, as they're already using VSCode to edit and run their work. Do you mean they should go to my repo on github.com and copypaste their work into some "new file" window there when they're finished?

Exactly! This could be an option.  which specific error is appearing when they are trying to commit/push? are they getting just the error in git right?

The error reads "You don't have permissions to push to "Teacher-Git-Username/Class-Repo-Name" on GitHub. Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead?
Your suggested fix isn't my preference. In terms of student experience, it's equivalent to paste-ing their work into a google doc. It does match the teacher end of the experience though

Ok, right, i understand! let’s switch back to discussing the error: did you know that in a GitHub repository, each branch can access its own code space? Are your students accessing their respective code spaces in their own branches? Have you configured that?

I think they are, how could I be able to tell?

You could check with some of your students to see if they are accessing their own branch on GitHub and if they are creating their CodeSpace within that branch. When they try to commit something, the files will be saved in this specific branch. Here's how you can see it: Access the repository, view the branches, and when you select one, you will notice that creating a CodeSpace saves the files just in this branch. On GitHub, there is a blue button labeled "Code"; when you click it, you will see an option with the message: "Create CodeSpace on [name of the branch]" or something similar.

if your students are creating their CodeSpaces in the main branch, it could lead to conflicts
